# Parsing name/value pairs from XML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am trying to pull account details from XML files supplied by vendors.

I have one vendor that supplied XML files like:

```xml
<Accounts>
  <Account>
    <AccountNumber>1234567</AccountNumber>
    <Balance>$200.00</Balance>
  </Account>
  <Account>
     ...
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

And I can parse this fairly easily using python:

```py
mytree = et.parse(xml_path)
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for acc in charges_root.findall('Account'):
    acctnum = acc.find('AccountNumber').text
    balance = acc.find('Balance').text
    print(acctnum, balance)
```

Which outputs like this:

```
1234567 $200.00
```

However another vendor supplies the XML files in something more like name/value pairs, and I am unsure how to easily access that data.  It doesn't work the same way as above:

```xml
<Accounts>
  <Account>
    <field name='AccountNumber' value='1234567' />
    <field name='Balance' value='$200.00' />
  </Account>
  <Account>
     ...
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

So far I've got this, but would like to be able to access the values separately and easily:

```py
mytree = et.parse(xml_path)
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for field in myroot.findall('Account'):
    for line in field:
        print(line.attrib)
```

Which outputs something like:

```
{'name': 'AccountNumber', 'value': '1234567'}
{'name': 'Balance', 'value': '$200.00'}
```

So my question is this - How can I access the values and assign them to variables (based on the `name`) so that I can make use of them elsewhere in the script, like I have with `acctnum` and `balance` in the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate a new datastructure (like a `dict`) from the `field` when you iterate instead of just discarding:

```
account_d = {}
for field in myroot.findall('Account'):
    for line in field:
        account_d[line.attrib['name']] = line.attrib['value']

    # account_d should now be:
    # { 'AccountNumber': '1234567', 'Balance': '$200.00' }
```

You can use a list of lists/tuples too:

```
account_a = []
for field in myroot.findall('Account'):
    for line in field:
        account_d.append(line.attrib['name'], line.attrib['value']) 

    # account_a should now be:
    # [('AccountNumber', '1234567'), ('Balance', '$200.00')]
```

Answer (score 2):

ElementTree 1.3 has the ability to locate nodes with particular attributes:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

data = '''\
<Accounts>
  <Account>
    <field name='AccountNumber' value='1234567' />
    <field name='Balance' value='$200.00' />
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <field name='AccountNumber' value='9999999' />
    <field name='Balance' value='$300.00' />
  </Account>
</Accounts>'''

tree = et.fromstring(data)

for acc in tree.iterfind('Account'):
    acctnum = acc.find("field[@name='AccountNumber']").attrib['value']
    balance = acc.find("field[@name='Balance']").attrib['value']
    print(acctnum,balance)
```

> ```
> 1234567 $200.00
> 9999999 $300.00
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by collecting all the `Account` element's `field` attributes into a dictionary and then using the information in it as needed:

**`accounts.xml`** sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Accounts>
  <Account>
    <field name='AccountNumber' value='1234567' />
    <field name='Balance' value='$200.00' />
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <field name='AccountNumber' value='8901234' />
    <field name='Balance' value='$100.00' />
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xml_path = 'accounts.xml'
mytree = et.parse(xml_path)
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for acct in myroot.findall('Account'):
    info = {field.attrib['name']: field.attrib['value']
                for field in acct.findall('field')}
    acctnum, balance = info['AccountNumber'], info['Balance']
    print(acctnum, balance)
```

Result:

```
1234567 $200.00
8901234 $100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: How can I access the values and assign them to variables  (based on the name)

Convert all Accounts to a Dict[AccountNumber] of Dict[field].
The Attribute `name` becomes the `dict` Key:

```
Accounts = {}
for account in root.findall('Account'):
    fields = {}
    for field in account.findall('field'):
        fields[field.attrib['name']] = field.attrib['value']

    print('{a[AccountNumber]} {a[Balance]}'.format(a=fields))
    Accounts[fields['AccountNumber']] = fields

print(Accounts)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> 1234567 $200.00
> 9999999 $300.00
> {'9999999': {'AccountNumber': '9999999', 'Balance': '$300.00'}, '1234567': {'AccountNumber': '1234567', 'Balance': '$200.00'}}
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***